# Will thermal paste help in cooling down the CPU of my Pi 4 even further?

Tags: pi-4, temperature, case, overclocking, cooling

I have the latest Raspberry Pi 4 (8gb edition), I'm using my Pi as a server to host a website, and to host a Discord bot that is being used in more than ~800 servers right now.

I overclocked my Pi, and I noticed that it was getting hot in the official casing of Pi 4, so I decided to get ICE Tower CPU Cooling Fan by 52Pi, which helped much to reduce the thermal issues. With the fan, the temperature of my Pi is usually ~40℃ (104°F).

[image: ICE Tower CPU Cooling Fan by 52Pi.]

The ICE Tower did come with thermal pads/stickers. Since I also have thermal paste at home, I was wondering if using thermal paste before applying the thermal sticker would help to reduce the temperature even more?

Comment: Best way to find out is to test it. You know the temperatures when it's not applied, so apply it and measure again ;)

Answer (score 4):

Your question should be "Which material has a lower thermal resistance: thermal paste, or thermal pads"? The material with the lower [thermal resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_resistance) will keep the temperature of your components coolest for any given heat sink.

To find the answer to your question, we should do an [Internet search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=thermal+resistance+thermal+paste+or+thermal+pads&t=ffnt&ia=shopping). This search yields a [link that contains the answer to your question.](https://blog.arctic.ac/blog/2015/07/23/thermal-pads-or-thermal-paste/)

According to the people at [arctic](https://www.arctic.ac/), the thermal paste "out-performs" thermal pads - meaning their thermal resistance is lower. So yes - thermal paste should help reduce the temperature of your RPi.

You could confirm this by tracking your CPU/GPU temperature using both methods (paste and pads) over a period of time while running a benchmark stress test.